# What does "Let the painter paint" mean?

Tags: meaning

Blake Halls, who own Fortico Security an armoured truck company, congraluate his employee
Patrick Hill for saving his colleague Bullet from hostages during routine pick up. Sitting in his car,
Hubbard contacts FBI Agent King to discuss about Patrick Hill as something the Bureau had
been looking for for 25 years:

> Hubbard: What do you want us to do?
>
> FBI Agent King: Not a fu*king thing. **Let the painter paint**.

What does "Let the painter paint" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an established idiom, but in context it means "Back off and let us do our job." The metaphor is an artist making a work of art; they need space and time, and crowding them will not help.

A similar, though not quite the same, idiom/proverb is [**too many cooks spoil the broth**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/too+many+cooks+spoil+the+broth).

Comment: I feel like there ought to be a *specific* verb / occupation serving as the archetypal "base" form for the general construction *Let the [verber] [verb]* - but the only *[verber]* that comes to mind is *Let the **cobbler** [stick to his last]*, which has completely different meaning.